# Count empty cells (mysql_num_rows) last 25 records

Tags: php

I have a little trouble to get empty cell from last 25 rows
My database contain 1000 articles, last 25 rows are without a title

I perform this query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT id title
FROM articles
WHERE title IS NOT NULL OR title != ''
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25                               
");
$total = mysql_num_rows($sql);
echo $total;
```

$total show 1000 (total rows), I expect to show 25 (rows without title)

Where do I wrong?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `mysql_*` functions. Is the code you're *updating* from 2012? Let me rephrase that, is it over *5* years old? Let me rephrase it again, if your webhost decides to migrate to PHP 7 your code will immediately fail which by the way has a performance increase of over 50%. 2 times as much users on the same server. It will be likely they will force you eventually. Happy upgrading to mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the exact opposite. If you want the ones that **are** empty, do this...

```
$sql = mysql_query("
  SELECT id, title
  FROM articles
  WHERE title IS NULL 
  OR title = ''
  ORDER BY id DESC 
  LIMIT 25                               
");
```

Comment: This is exactly right, although I'd suggest removing the `LIMIT` at the end of the query - no reason to use a limit in this situation. (@eeetee I know you just copied over his SQL, this comment is directed at @HidDencum)